# R ggplotly animated geom_tile

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I have this dataframe

```
dt <-
data.frame(
        date = as.Date(c("2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-02")),
        seq = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2),
        days = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
        val = seq(1, 8))
```

I'd like to create animated geom_tile and geom_text plots in ggplotly where animation frames will be days. I created this code:

```
  ggplotly(
    ggplot(
      dt,
      aes(x = seq, y = date, fill = days)) +
      geom_tile(frame = days) +
      geom_text(aes(label = val), frame = days) +
      facet_grid(days~.) 
  )
```

But I'm getting following warning and there is no animation at all.

```
Warning messages: 
1: Ignoring unknown parameters: frame  
2: Ignoring > unknown parameters: frame
```

In other words, expected result for first frame is

```
  ggplotly(
    ggplot(
      dt %>% 
      filter(days == 1),
      aes(x = seq, y = date, fill = days)) +
      geom_tile(frame = days) +
      geom_text(aes(label = val), frame = days) +
      facet_grid(days~.) 
  )
```

and second frame should be

```
  ggplotly(
    ggplot(
      dt %>% 
      filter(days == 2),
      aes(x = seq, y = date, fill = days)) +
      geom_tile(frame = days) +
      geom_text(aes(label = val), frame = days) +
      facet_grid(days~.) 
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your expected output is. If you want to set `frame`, do this in `ggplot(aes())`. However, you're not going to be able to facet on the same variable as you use for `frame`.

```
ggplotly(
  ggplot(dt, aes(x = seq, y = date, fill = days, frame = days)) +
    geom_tile() +
    geom_text(aes(label = val)) 
)
```

[image] [image]